# What is an Handler?

Tags: asp.net

Very noob question,

In asp.net can you explain in the simplest possible way "*what is an handler*?"
How can you use handlers..

Thanks a lot.

Comment: talking about httphandlers ? or event handlers ?

Comment: anything missing from my answer that would help? :)

Comment: Your answer is really clear but i've seen something like that:
 [Category("Action"), Description("Event when filter change")]
    public event EventHandler FilterChanged;

How does it work? it's the same thing as a function like in your example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean an "event handler", or something that inherits from `IHttpHandler`? In both cases handler describes something that reacts to an event occuring. An event handler would be, for example, a method that is called when a button is clicked:

```
public void MyButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Code to respond to the button click here
}
```

Something that inherits from `IHttpHandler` could be, for example, a page in an ASP.net Web Forms application (as all pages you create inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page` which in turn inherits from `IHttpHandler`) or a "Generic Handler" (a file usually with the extension .ashx).

An example of a generic handler would be:

```
public class MyGenericHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Write("Hello, world!");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This would be more performant than having an ASP.net Web Forms page that did similar as it doesn't need to build all the Web Forms "framework" of the page lifecycle, viewstate and so on for each request, which means that it's better suited to requests that don't need to render presentation/markup, such as anything that would be responding to an AJAX request.

Answer (score 2):

A *handler* is a piece of code which is called when something happens, and usually takes some action, like generating a response.

A *HTTP handler* is called when a HTTP request is done, and it *handles* the request. That is, it creates some response depending on what the request is.

Comment: like this for succinctness.  As an EG to handler: think of a button.  A button will be there and you can click it and it won't do anything.  The even handler is the function that is called to make the button *do* something (submit a form, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

[ASP.NET Introduction to HTTP Handlers:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28VS.80%29.aspx)

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Handler -> `HttpHandler` is anything that can process an HttpRequest and produce response in any form. All ASP.NET Pages are HttpHandlers and they produce HTML output that is sent to requesting client/browser.